# Async/Await for a search function that calls the api within a react-native-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I am new to React Native and need your help.

I have an api call for my search function, which calls on different recipes depending on the users input. I have created the async/await api call in a different file. I console log it and everything works fine. It spits out the json in the console. However I want to implement this call in my SearchScreen, which is the file attached below.

In the handleSearch function I call the api which is the `getRecipesFromApiByRecipeName(text);` method. The `text` is the user input.

I know that somehow I need to make a async function, that I can receive my api call and not receive

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

the whole time. But how...

I have heard that one can do the api call in the `ComponentDidMount()` function, as this can be made async, but the Api will and must only be called once the user has entered his query and not once the Component has mounted.

I have also tried using the `.then` function, which should somehow "unpromise" the Json, but had no luck with that.

So what I would like to happen is that the api gets called once the user has given an input and that the json can be added into the Screen. If you could suggest what I should do or even show me some code snippets. Maybe my whole way of attacking this things is wrong, all I want is that the recipes are displayed on the device.. so even if you have a brand new idea of how to implement the api calls, let me know, I would really appreciate it.

Also let me know if there is anything else I should fix on this Screen.

I am also having difficulties understanding how the whole "state" thing works, so If that could be explained as well, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import MenuImage from '../../components/MenuImage/MenuImage';
import { getRecipesFromApiByRecipeName } from '../../data/Data';

export default class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      headerRight: () =>
        <MenuImage
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.openDrawer();
          }}
        />
      ,
      headerTitle: () =>
        <SearchBar
          containerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopColor: 'transparent',
            width: 300

          }}
          inputContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
            borderRadius: 25
          }}
          inputStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
            borderRadius: 5,
            color: 'black'
          }}
          searchIcon
          clearIcon
          onChangeText={text => params.handleSearch(text)}
          placeholder="Search"
          value={params.data}
        />
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      data: []
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.setParams({
      handleSearch: this.handleSearch,
      data: this.getValue
    });
  }

  handleSearch = text => {
    const recipes = getRecipesFromApiByRecipeName(text); //need to get this to be able to call await.
      if (text == '') {
        this.setState({
          value: text,
          data: []
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          value: text,
          data: recipes
        });
      }
  };

  getValue = () => {
    return this.state.value;
  };

  onPressRecipe = item => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Recipe', { item });
  };

  renderRecipes = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,0.9)' onPress={() => this.onPressRecipe(item)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.photo} source={{ uri: item.recipe.image }} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.recipe.label}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          vertical
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          numColumns={2}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderRecipes}
          keyExtractor={item => `${item.recipeId}`} //How does this work?
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the syntactic rules of JavaScript, the keyword `await` can only do what it needs to do within an `async` function.

```js
function a() {
  // await is not a keyword in a regular function
  var await = 5;
  console.log(await);
}

a()

async function b() {
//^^^
  // but it is a special keyword in an async function
  // by using await, we pause the code execution
  // until the promise we're awaiting one is fulfilled
  const x = await Promise.resolve(10);
  console.log(x);
}

b();
```

This rule stands for arrow functions as well:

```js
const a = () => {
  // await is not a keyword in a regular function
  var await = 5;
  console.log(await);
}

a()

const b = async () => {
  //      ^^^^^
  // but it is a special keyword in an async function
  // by using await, we pause the code execution
  // until the promise we're awaiting one is fulfilled
  const x = await Promise.resolve(10);
  console.log(x);
}

b();
```

In your case, `handleSearch` is a regular arrow function, so `await` cannot work within it. You need to make `handleSearch` an `async` function that `await`'s on the recipes:

```
handleSearch = async text => {
//             ^^^^^
    const recipes = await getRecipesFromApiByRecipeName(text);
//                  ^^^^^
```